# Store query in array in bash

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

My script need to store in a structure the result of a query:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 user="..."
 psw="..."
 database="..."
 query="select name, mail from t"
 customStructure=$(mysql -u$user -p$psw $database -e "$query";)
```

I've no idea how store the array of {name, mail} from query result..

I need structure like this:

```
 array=[ [name1,mail1] , [name2,mail2], ....., [nameN, mailN] ]
```

Is there a way to do this in bash?

Comment: why bash? u can use others language like php, python, ruby to do the same job, and probably is much easier

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bash arrays are initialized like so:

```
myarray=("hi" 1 "2");
```

To capture the individual portions of output of a command into an array, we must loop through the output, adding it's results to the array. That can be done like so:

```
for i in `echo "1 2 3 4"`
do
    myarray+=($i)
done
```

In your example, it looks like you wish to get the output of a MySQL command and store the parts of it's output lines into subarrays. I will show you how to capture lines into arrays, and given that, you should be able to figure out how to put subarrays into that yourself.

```
while read line
do 
    myarray+=("$line")
done < <(mysql -u${user} -p${psw} ${database} -e "${query}")
```

It's also worth mentioning that for this kind of MySQL operation, where you don't need output metadata (such as pretty formatting and table names), you can use MySQL's `-B` option to do 'batch output'.

Comment: No problem, I'm really happy I was able to help! If you'd like to learn more about Bash array's on your own check out the examples here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html

Answer (score 3):

Field level record can be accessed via `read -a` command and `IFS` is set to the empty string to prevent read from stripping leading and trailing whitespace from the line.

```
#!/bin/bash
user="..."
psw="..."
database="..."
query="select name, mail from t"

OIFS="$IFS" ; IFS=$'\n' ; oset="$-" ; set -f

while IFS="$OIFS" read -a line 
do 
  echo ${line[0]}   
  echo ${line[1]}   
done < <(mysql  -u${user} -p${psw} ${database} -e "${query}")
```

Comment: Doesn't work with spaces in returned values, as they will be split into separate items of the array by read -a.

Comment: Also the first line will be the column names. not the cleanest, but better would be to add: | sed 's# #_#g' | sed 1d